# For $S\subset V$, under what conditions does $f\colon S\to W$ extend to a linear map $\hat{f}\colon\text{span}(S)\to W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $S\subset V$ be any (possibly infinite) subset. Under what conditions does a map $f\colon S\to W$ extend to a linear map $\hat{f}\colon\text{span}(S)\to W$?

Here $\text{span}(S)\subset V$ denotes the set of all finite linear combinations of elements in $S$.

I think that $S$ must be linearly independ, i.e., any finite subset $F\subset S$ is linearly independent. Is this correct? And if so, is this sufficient?

Comment: Well, it need not be linearly independent provided $f$ is already linear as it is defined.

Comment: @TedShifrin $S$ may not have a linear structure.

Comment: Of course, but if $v$ and $3v$ are in $S$, for example, then $f(3v)$ must equal $3f(v)$, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is: for all collections $x_1,\dots,x_n \in S$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb C$ such that $\sum \alpha_k x_k = 0$ the equality $\sum \alpha_k f(x_k) = 0$ holds.

Obviously, the condition is necessary. To prove that it is sufficient consider $x \in span(S)$. If $x = \sum \alpha_k x_k = \sum \beta_m y_m$, $x_k,y_m \in S$, then $\sum \alpha_k f(x_k)  = \sum \beta_m f(y_m)$ in view of the condition on $f$. Thus, we can define $\hat f(x)$ as $\sum \alpha_k f(x_k)$ (the definition is independent of the representation of $x$ in the form of $\sum \alpha_k x_k$, $x_1,\dots,x_n \in S$). This map is obviously linear.

Observe that for linearly independent $S$ the condition holds for arbitrary $f$.

Comment: In particular, **every** map extends iff $S$ is linearly independent.